# How to set HTML for the new post - socket.io & javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, socket.io

I have created a real-time blog site using socket.io and Laravel 5.3. Everything is working great technically.

By saying real-time, I mean that whenever somebody creates a new post, it will be automatically appended on the top of the blog listing page.

This is what I have done so far:

1) When a user access \posts URL, I'm fetching all the posts from the database and then display on the view using a loop.

2) When somebody creates a new post, get the new post data in javascript using socket.io.

3) Clone the HTML of the first post from the listing page and use it as template and change the content using jQuery

So my question is,

How should I set HTML for the new post in a better way? Currently, I'm doing this and it is working perfectly:

Get the first < div > of the post which is there on the listing page, then clone the  < div > and append it on the top and then change the inner text like blog title, body etc...

**HTML and PHP:**

```
<div id="article-container" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    @foreach($articles as $article)
    <article class="article-tmp">
        <h3>
            <a href="{{ route('article.show', !empty($article->id)) }}">{{ $article->title or '' }}</a>
        </h3>
        <blockquote>{{ $article->text or '' }}</blockquote>
    </article>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.Echo.channel('new-article')
    .listen('NewArticle', (data) => {

        if($('#article-container').length) {
            var articleTmp = $('.article-tmp');
            var articleEle = articleTmp.clone().prependTo('#article-container');
            articleEle.find('h3 a').text(data.article.title);
            articleEle.find('blockquote').text(data.article.text);
        }
});
```

I know this could be one of the solutions:

Keep blank HTML markup hidden into the template like:

```
<article class="article-tmp hidden">
  <h3><a></a></h3>
  <blockquote></blockquote>
</article>
```

and then use it in js, as a blog template instead of copying the first one.

All I need is a better way. It is fine if somebody can just show me rough ideas - no need for code.

Thanks